# How to ensure server 2016 is getting all the latest patches

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update, windows-patching

I ran a Nessus scan on my Server 2016 server and got the following error:

"The remote Windows host is missing security update 4571694."

When doing some research on the patch I found this article

"https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4571694/windows-10-update-kb4571694"

If you scroll down to the bottomish of that page you will see the "How to get this update" section and it says

"Windows Update and Microsoft Update    Yes None. This update will be downloaded and installed automatically from Windows Update."

From powershell I can see it is not installed:

[image]

I looked at all the update setting and cannot see why the update was not installed. I know I can download and install the patch manually however I am curious why windows update is not installing it for me.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

> why windows update is not installing it for me

Windows updates are cumulative. 4577015 supersedes 4571694.

The problem is not Windows, it is your scanner is not up to date.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/20200908/security-update-deployment-information-september-8-2020